# My directive is executed before ngRepeat and ngInclude, despite of default priority 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

My custom directives compile function is executed before ngRepeat (priority=1000) and ngInclude (priority=400), despite of default priority is 0, so it should be executed after.

Snippet shows that content appended by myDir directive is missing, only shows included content from ngInclude template:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('test.html', '<p>Content included by ngInclude</p><span>Number {{$index}}</span>');
})
.directive("myDir", function() {
    return {
        compile: function(elm){
            elm.append('<span>apended by directive myDir, 1+1={{1+1}}</span>');
            return function link(){};
        }
    };
})
.controller("myApp", function($scope){
    $scope.items = [1,2,3];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myApp">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" my-dir="" ng-include="'test.html'"><p>First content</p></div>
</div>
```

I have same code in jsfiddle here: [jsfiddle-link](http://jsfiddle.net/luckylooke/y1q7h9pg/)
There it shows expected behaviour. Appended text from directive is shown.
Because of lowest priority text is appended after ngRepeat and ngInclude compile functions.

Difference between examples is in angular versions only. Snipped here runs on v1.2.23 (same behaviour as in my project running v1.3.0) and jsfiddle runs on v1.2.1

Any advice is welcome, thanks in advance ;)

PS: In jsfiddle example, there is "`<span>Number {{$index}}</span>`" part missing in view, extra score for those who tell me why.

Comment: I know how to bypass the problem, but it seems to me as bug in angularjs, isnt it?

Comment: Is the question: "why there is a difference in behavior between Angular versions" or is the question "how do I do accomplish X with Angular ver. Y"?

Comment: Why is angular v1.2.23+ ignoring directive priority and runs lowest priority custom directive before higher priority level inbuild directives ngInclude and ngRepeat, which breaks documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they added the `ngIncludeFillContentDirective` directive (also registered under the `ngInclude` name), which replaces the entire html:

```
var ngIncludeFillContentDirective = ['$compile',
  function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'ECA',
      priority: -400,
      require: 'ngInclude',
      link: function(scope, $element, $attr, ctrl) {
        if (/SVG/.test($element[0].toString())) {
          // WebKit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=135698 --- SVG elements do not
          // support innerHTML, so detect this here and try to generate the contents
          // specially.
          $element.empty();
          $compile(jqLiteBuildFragment(ctrl.template, document).childNodes)(scope,
              function namespaceAdaptedClone(clone) {
            $element.append(clone);
          }, {futureParentElement: $element});
          return;
        }

        $element.html(ctrl.template);
        $compile($element.contents())(scope);
      }
    };
  }];
```

It runs on priority -400, so your directive is executed after ngRepeat and ngInclude but before this one.

Comment: I have tried to set myDir directive priority to -500 to be executed after ngIncludeFillContentDirective, but nothing changed :/ (I didnt realise priority can be negative value, thanks :) ) But you give me at least the trace I can investigate more. So thank you!

Comment: I cant see how ngInclude is using ngIncludeFillContentDirective... I see that ngIncludeFillContentDirective is defined and requires ngInclude but how it gets into be executed?

Comment: they are both registered under the same name `ngInclude` so angular applies them both when finding the `ng-include` attribute on the element

Comment: Aha, I have found it now, thanks.. I didnt know that it can be done.. registering more than one directives under same name.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think that problem is that ngInclude is terminal.

ng [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> terminal
>
> If set to true then the current priority will be the last set of
>   directives which will execute (any directives at the current priority
>   will still execute as the order of execution on same priority is
>   undefined). Note that expressions and other directives used in the
>   directive's template will also be excluded from execution.

This is my workaround (DOM manipulation in link fn instead of compile fn):

```js
angular.module("app", [])
.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('test.html', '<p>Content included by ngInclude</p><span>Number {{$index}}</span>');
})
.directive("myDir", function($compile) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elm){
            elm.append($compile('<br><span>apended by directive myDir, 1+1={{1+1}}</span>')(scope));
        }
    };
})
.controller("myApp", function($scope){
    $scope.items = [1,2,3];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myApp">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" my-dir="" ng-include="'test.html'"><p>First content</p></div>
</div>
```